# PCL Reflection get properties with BindingFlags

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, portable-class-library

I have the code below.

```
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllPublicInstanceDeclaredOnlyProperties(this Type type)
    {
        var result =
            from PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
            select pi;

        return result;
    }
```

I am trying to convert this to a PCL library but I can not figure it out. I have tried

```
type.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Where(x => x.BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

But BindingFlags doesn't exist.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this not work `type.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).ToList()`

Comment: No. GetProperties doesnt exist in PCL

Comment: Any progress since then?

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx), `GetProperties` method is supported:

> Supported in: Portable Class Library

Make sure you've included `System.Reflection` namespace.

`GetProperties()` is part of the `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` class (a bunch of reflection extension methods) so include the namespace and you should have this and similar extensions available.

If it's still not available, try include `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` assembly via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions/).

```
PM> Install-Package System.Reflection.TypeExtensions
```

Comment: *BindingFlags* does not exist.  System.Reflection.TypeExtensions is not compatible with PCL.  This is not a valid answer.